# nginx reuseport with backlog

Tags: linux, nginx, tcp

In nginx if I specify `reuseport` and `backlog=X`

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 8080 backlog=X reuseport;
```

will I get a maximum queue length of size `X` per socket/worker or a max total queue of size `X`?

Answer (score 1):

I went to look at the nginx source code and it seems to me that it is `X` per socket/worker:

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/751bdd3bb2b6ff54be09c37ff328f258fed520fb/src/core/ngx_connection.c#L119

https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/751bdd3bb2b6ff54be09c37ff328f258fed520fb/src/core/ngx_connection.c#L654

but I'm not very familiar with the nginx codebase.